# How to Preventing initialize variable error in Java

Tags: java, variables, scheduled-tasks, final, runnable

I am trying to get this program to cancel itself after running 3 times, but I keep getting a "The local variable taskId may not have been initialized" error. For one is this dangerous. Two can I still properly compile it and run the program despite getting compiler errors? Lastly how would I fix this? Thanks!

```
final int taskId = plugin.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(plugin, new Runnable() {
    int count = 0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ((LivingEntity) e.getEntity()).damage(2);
        count++;
        if (count > 2) {
            Bukkit.getScheduler().cancelTask(taskId);
        }
    }

}, 60L);
```

Comment: "can I still properly compile it despite getting compiler errors"???

Comment: `can I still properly compile it despite getting compiler errors?` Man, you need to first get into basics of programming b4 u try such high level stuff

Comment: unfortunately the "just trust me on this one"-switch has not been implemented yet in any compiler.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible you will try to use the taskId before it is initialised.

This will not work in your case, because it is not access only in `cancelTask(taskId)` but when the anonymous class is constructed. i.e. before it has been set.

A work around is to use a `int[] task` instead but this is risky.

A simpler work around is to throw a RuntimeException such as `IllegalStateException` or one of your own as this will stop the task repeating.